# Windows system login credentials

Tags: c#, system, scheduled-tasks

i am developing a scheduler in which i want to match the username and password entered by the user with the system's login credentials in c#.Is there any way to do this.

Comment: what if there is no user logged in, or better, multiple users logged-in?

Comment: But task scheduler always ask for login credentials failing which the task is not processes. alos, scheduler will be used on the server which is bound to have a login credential

Comment: what does this task do such that it needs to be impersonated by the logged-in user? AFAIK, you can set only 1 identity for the task, and it will execute on behalf of that identity.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use the Windows Task Scheduler?

Just look http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/tsnewlib.aspx

BTW you can gather the currently logged on user by using System.Environment or from the current Thread.

Answer (score 1):

```
 WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

Getting the default credentials for the current user:

```
CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```